# Operand Data type float is invalid for modulo operator, float to int with LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, linq-to-entities

I was trying to fetch data from Sql using LINQ and do some operation like rounding of my number to nearest 1000 when the value is greater than 500. I have the column costreproductionnew(float,null) and buildingOverride.

if buildingoveride has value it should be considered else costreproductionNew

I am unable to perform operation as I am getting inner exception **'Operand Data type float is invalid for modulo operator'**

```
allBuildings.Sum(b => (b.BuildingOverride.HasValue && b.BuildingOverride > 0)
                                                           ? b.BuildingOverride.Value

: (b.CostReproductionNew.HasValue ? (Math.Round(b.CostReproductionNew.Value) > 500)
                                                          ? (Math.Round(b.CostReproductionNew.Value) % 1000 >= 500
                                                                ? Math.Round(b.CostReproductionNew.Value) + 1000 - Math.Round(b.CostReproductionNew.Value) % 1000
                                                                   : Math.Round(b.CostReproductionNew.Value) - Math.Round(b.CostReproductionNew.Value) % 1000)
                                                                    : 500
                                                                   : 0)
```

***Can anyone help me how to convert from float to int here?***

Formula used for rounding to 1000 in simpler version (for better readability)

x = x % 1000 >= 500 ? x + 1000 - x % 1000 : x - x % 1000;

Comment: I haven't looked too closely at your formula, but based mainly on the description of your problem is there any reason why you can't just use something like `Math.Max( Math.Round((b.CostReproductionNew.Value/ 1000) * 1000 , 500)` ?

Comment: Thanks for lookinng on this. 
b.CostReplacementNew.HasValue (((int)Math.Round(b.ContentCostReproductionNew.Value)) > 500)

by adding Int before it helped me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

```
b.CostReplacementNew.HasValue (((int)Math.Round(b.ContentCostReproductionNew.Value)) > 500)
```

by adding (int) before it helped me to resolve this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).